# PHP tabular order form

Tags: php, html, forms, tabular

I made an online order form which is basically an html Table. Each cells of this table are inputs for desired quantities. Everything works fine.

The visitor and I are receiving the filled table by mail but i'd like to receive only the lines of the table which contains at least one filled indput. We have more than 100 products and it would be easier to managed "filtered" order-forms.

Here is the html table

```
<form class="form-mini" name="form-mini" method="POST" action="submit.php?<?PHP echo SID; ?>">
    <table class="tableur">
<tr>
<th>Product name</th> 

<th>quantity for option 1</th>
<th>quantity for option 2</th>
<th>quantity for option 3</th> 
<th>quantity for option 4</th> 
<th>quantity for option 5</th>  
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Cool Product 1</td>
 <td class="zero"  align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_1"></td>
 <td class="trois" align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_2"></td>
 <td class="huit"  align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_3"></td>
 <td class="douze" align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_4"></td>
 <td class="seize" align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Other cool product</td>
 <td class="zero" align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_6"></td>
 <td class="trois"align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_7"></td>
 <td class="huit" align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_8"></td>
 <td class="douze"align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_9"></td>
 <td class="seize"align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="b_10"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
```

Here is a bit of my php which is basically a "send order by mail in a html table style. Theses are just a few code snippets in order to illustrate my issue "

```
    <?php

    // vars

    $b_1   = $_POST['b_1'];
    $b_2   = $_POST['b_2'];
    $b_3   = $_POST['b_3'];
    $b_4   = $_POST['b_4'];
    $b_5   = $_POST['b_5'];
    $b_6   = $_POST['b_6'];
    $b_7   = $_POST['b_7'];
    $b_8   = $_POST['b_8'];
    $b_9   = $_POST['b_9'];
    $b_10   = $_POST['b_10'];

$message = "
<tr>
<td>Cool Product 1</td>
<td>$b_1</td>
<td>$b_2</td>
<td>$b_3</td>
<td>$b_4</td>
<td>$b_5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Other Cool Product</td>
<td>$b_6</td>
<td>$b_7</td>
<td>$b_8</td>
<td>$b_9</td>
<td>$b_10</td>
</tr>
"
```

I know that my code is rudimentary but it do at least part of the job. Any tips to solve my issue would be highly appreciated. I searched a method with json or ajax but I'm a total coding noob. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```html
do a loop checking if the product value is more than  one, for example 


<?php foreach ($_POST as $product => $value){ 

      if ($value != "" ){
               echo "<td>$product Quantity: $value</td>
                        }
                }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Billy. I was reading about the foreach function and i'm gonna try your tip. But I wonder if this solution will preserve the table format in the mail and keep the adjacents empty <td>'s.

Comment: it will only echo a td if the value is equal to or greater than 1, for example if a checkbox is checked, just looked more closely at your code, I should have done before answering but i was going out quickly, i see you have text inouts, you will have to check the values differently depending on what is in the input. for example , check if it's not empty , I've edited my code to check there is a value in the input, and only if there is will it echo a td.

Comment: I was messing with your previous solution and documentation about foreach on the web but im still knocking my head on a wall as every examples uses the php "array" object and not a ugly <table> as I do. ( its the first time im using php). The inputs are texts but should be numbers as they are dedicated to quantities. If you wanna see what the order form looks like [link](http://hell-juice.com)